# Only display 1 error message when there are 2 validation errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a timepicker in AngularJS where you can select multiple different time segments for each day. I have validation in the code which checks for duplicates and any time segments that overlap. If I enter the following 2 time segments, 11:00am - 12:00am and 11:00am - 12:00am, I get 2 validation error messages - 'Overlapping times entered' and 'Duplicate times entered'.

This is working as expected as both validations are occurring, in this scenario, however, I would just want 'Duplicate times entered' to be displayed. Please have a look at this image for validation error:

[image]

The code I have for this is:

```js
public validateNoDuplicates(timeSegments : string[][]) : void {
        let seen : object = {};
        let timeSegmentsWithoutDuplicates : string[][] = [];

        let skipValidationCount : number = 0;
        for (let i : number = 0, l : number = timeSegments.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (this.isValidTimeSegment(timeSegments[i])) {
                let timeSegmentIdentifier : string = timeSegments[i].join();
                if (!seen[timeSegmentIdentifier]) {
                    timeSegmentsWithoutDuplicates.push(timeSegments[i]);
                    seen[timeSegmentIdentifier] = 'found';
                }
            } else {
                skipValidationCount++;
            }
        }

        if (timeSegmentsWithoutDuplicates.length !== timeSegments.length - skipValidationCount) {
            this.validationMessages.push(this.DUPLICATE_TIMES_ENTERED);
        }
}

public validateNoOverlaps(timeSegments : string[][]) : void {
    let sortedTimeSegments : string[][] = angular.copy(timeSegments);
    sortedTimeSegments.sort(); // Sort time segments by start time

        for (let i : number = 0; i < sortedTimeSegments.length - 1; i++) {
            if (this.isValidTimeSegment(sortedTimeSegments[i]) &&          this.isValidTimeSegment(sortedTimeSegments[i + 1])) {
                let endTimeOfCurrentTimeSegment : string = sortedTimeSegments[i][this.END_TIME_INDEX];

                let startTimeOfNextTimeSegment : string = sortedTimeSegments[i + 1][this.START_TIME_INDEX];

                if (endTimeOfCurrentTimeSegment > startTimeOfNextTimeSegment) {

                    this.validationMessages.push(this.OVERLAPPING_TIMES_ENTERED);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<div ng-show="$ctrl.daypartingValidator.validationMessages.length > 0">
  <div>
    <h6>Please correct the following errors:</h6>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <div ng-repeat="validationMessage in $ctrl.daypartingValidator.validationMessages" >
      <span>{{validationMessage}}</span>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

--Update--
I cannot check the array for 'Overlapping times entered' message as in some cases, like the one below, the 2 messages need to appear:

[valid errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtgat.png)

--Updated--

I have updated the code to check if the start and end times match the next start and end times. The issue now if time segments like - 01:00am - 05:00am & 01:00am - 04:00am, are entered. If there is overlapping but either the start or end time match the next start or end time then the message will not appear.

```js
for (let i : number = 0; i < sortedTimeSegments.length - 1; i++) {
            if (this.isValidTimeSegment(sortedTimeSegments[i]) && this.isValidTimeSegment(sortedTimeSegments[i + 1])) {
                let endTimeOfCurrentTimeSegment : string = sortedTimeSegments[i][this.END_TIME_INDEX] == this.TWELVE_AM ? "24:00" :
                    sortedTimeSegments[i][this.END_TIME_INDEX];

                let endTimeOfNextTimeSegment : string = sortedTimeSegments[i + 1][this.END_TIME_INDEX] == this.TWELVE_AM ? "24:00" :
                    sortedTimeSegments[i + 1][this.END_TIME_INDEX];

                let startTimeOfNextTimeSegment : string = sortedTimeSegments[i + 1][this.START_TIME_INDEX];
                let startTimeOfCurrentTimeSegment : string = sortedTimeSegments[i][this.START_TIME_INDEX];

                if (endTimeOfCurrentTimeSegment > startTimeOfNextTimeSegment) {

                    if ((startTimeOfCurrentTimeSegment != startTimeOfNextTimeSegment) &&
                            (endTimeOfCurrentTimeSegment != endTimeOfNextTimeSegment)) {
                        this.validationMessages.push(this.OVERLAPPING_TIMES_ENTERED);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think we'll need also the html snippet

Comment: I don't think I would change this. As a user, it would be frustrating to fix one issue only to find I actually had two. Showing both ensures that the user has a chance to act on both at the same time rather than one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the HTML I can only suggest that before you push an OVERLAPPING_TIMES validation message, check if there is already a DUPLICATE_TIMES message in the array.

EDIT: Change the code for OVERLAPPING_TIMES to not push the message if the start and end times match exactly.

EDIT2: Use `||` to push the OVERLAPPING_TIMES message because if either of them don't match, then they are not actually duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have updated the post with the HTML code, the problem with checking the array for a DUPLICATE_TIMES message is that there might be 2 other time segments in the array that are duplicates

Comment: @BrianM I see, in that case you might want to have your validation array track which time segments are conflicting. That way you can actually track if the DUPLICATE_TIMES and OVERLAPPING_TIMES are originating from the same conflict.

Comment: Actually, the easiest way would be to not push an OVERLAPPING_TIMES message if the start times and end times match exactly.

Comment: Thanks @mintychai that answer was useful. I think I nearly have it. I think the only problem I have now is if time like - 01:00 - 06:00 & 01:00 - 05:00 - is entered, no messages appear as the start times both match. I have updated the code that i have for it

Comment: Easy fix! Your line `if ((startTimeOfCurrentTimeSegment != startTimeOfNextTimeSegment) &&
                            (endTimeOfCurrentTimeSegment != endTimeOfNextTimeSegment))` should use OR instead (:

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code to use 'or' instead of 'and' and this resolved it:

```js
if (startTimeOfCurrentTimeSegment != startTimeOfNextTimeSegment ||
                            endTimeOfCurrentTimeSegment !=            endTimeOfNextTimeSegment) {
                        this.validationMessages.push(this.OVERLAPPING_TIMES_ENTERED);
                    }
```